# Spark: Getting SQLException: Unsupported type -101 reading from Oracle

Tags: oracle, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to sqoop data from Oracle using Scala and I am getting the below error:

I have Oracle datatypes as CLOB.

Could you please advise.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported type -101
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JDBCRDD$$getCatalystType(JDBCRDD.scala:105)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$$anonfun$1.apply(JDBCRDD.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$$anonfun$1.apply(JDBCRDD.scala:155)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:154)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation.<init>(JDBCRelation.scala:117)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:330)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:149)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:122)

        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:736)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSub
```

Comment: I have dataypes in oracle like varchar2,number,timestamp,clob

Comment: `CLOB` should be mapped to a Java `String` although a specific driver may have a different opinion. `NUMBER(*)` (without explicit precision/scale) or `NUMBER(p,-s)` ("negative" scale) are problematic because no other framework on the galaxy supports these things, i.e. floating-point with 38 digits and integer x10^s